# How to compare the field to all the rows returned by subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

```
WHERE a.field = (SELECT a.field FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.field = b.field)
```

HOW can i compare? this query returned this error statement 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Is that possible to compare it to all the returned by the subquery?

Comment: Not sure if your logic is incomplete, but changing the subquery to `SELECT ... where ... LIMIT 1` or maybe `SELECT MAX(a.field)` will force the subquery to return exactly one row.

Comment: @ryanyuyu i want to compare it with all the rows returned by the subqueries

Comment: Please describe the result set you want the query to return, and, ideally, the tables involved in the query.

Comment: @FredSobotka it returns the rows of account id value. And i want to compared each..row value to the given in the where a.field

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. Please edit your question to show what your tables look like, and type in an example of the result set you're trying to achieve so we can better understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be be able use the IN clause with a subquery:

WHERE a.field IN (SELECT a.field FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.field = b.field)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

You can compare all the rows in three ways.

Use `In` operator

```
WHERE ou.field in (SELECT a.field 
                   FROM a 
                   INNER JOIN b 
                   ON a.field = b.field)
```

or use `Exists`

```
WHERE exists (SELECT a.field 
                   FROM a 
                   INNER JOIN b 
                   ON a.field = b.field
                   where ou.field=a.field)
```

or use `Inner Join`

```
Ou Inner Join (SELECT a.field 
                   FROM a 
                   INNER JOIN b 
                   ON a.field = b.field) c
   On ou.field = c.field
```